# can you add src and play in js and html

Tags: javascript, html

This is not working for me. I created script src to my HTML

```js
function eyob1() {   
    var play1 = document.getElementById("aud").src="eyobmknn/trk1.mp3"
    play1.loop = "true";
    pley1.play();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="launch.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div onclick="openeyob();" class="eyob" id="eyob">Eyob Mekonnen</div>
    <div id="container">
    <div onclick="eyob1();" class="eyob1" id="eyob">01 track 01 

    <script  src="lunch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and I can add src but the sound cannot be played

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yoo dont have element with ID aud

Answer (score 1):

I answared a similar question here: [How to play audio loaded via file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69691127/how-to-play-audio-loaded-via-file-input/69691858#69691858)

It's possible to change the src attribute using the method SetAtrribute:

```
function eyob1() {   
    var play1 = document.getElementById("aud")
    play1.settAtribute('src', "eyobmknn/trk1.mp3")
}
```

But is important to notice that your code does't have a an element with id='audio'. Your script won't work as it is now.

A good start point is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials